# Purpose of django-environ?

Tags: django, environment-variables

What is DJANGO-ENVIRON ?

For what it can be used and How to use it ?

I saw django-environ in one project, try to understand it and unsuccess,
it's [doc](https://django-environ.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#)

but understand nothing

Comment: "Django-environ allows you to utilize 12factor inspired environment variables to configure your Django application." Line 1 of your own link.

Comment: Django-Environ is good, but projects docs are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example lets say you have the development environment (the computer you're doing development on) and the deployment environment (the server you're doing to publish the server on) instead of dealing with the path of each file or database once in every environment, you could set them as an environment variable in the server and the development machine, you could just tell the settings.py to look for the path in the environment variable.

thats as simple as i can get it.

Comment: thaks a lot! )))  I think have understood a little bit!